# How can I access _subscribers data view from child business unit?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, data-views

As the title suggests I would like to query out `_Subscribers` from within a child Business Unit.

When running my query

`select SubscriberKey, EmailAddress
from _subscribers`

No results are returned, no errors are shown either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to prefix "ent" eg `ent._subscribers`